# How to change TinyMCE source code dialog box and preview like wordpress editor preview and source dialog box

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, summernote

Generally TinyMce Editor have a features to view the source code like the image bellow

[image]

Is there any way to make the source code dialog and preview dialog as like as

[image]

I need only the layout in which both the preview and source code editor align within the whole text box not within a modal just as like as wordpress editor.

Is there any way to do it, how?

TinyMCE only provides two properties `code_dialog_height: code_dialog_width:` and nothing else to customize the source window. It also provides the section menu bar or toolbar to show the switch icon.

Comment: What you want is pretty clear, but did you research *anything* at all?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried with it from the whole day but did not find any luck. I have also tried with summernote and CKeditor, but did not like these editor so I have asked this question. do you have any idea?

Comment: This does not mean that, I have tried to find any way to make it through google the whole day also read the necessary docs from www.tinymce.com but did not get any solution So I have to ask here. why do you think like that?

Comment: TinyMCE only provides 
code_dialog_height: 
code_dialog_width:
these two propertise nothing else to customize the source window, Also it provides the section menu bar or toolbar to show the switch icon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145291/discussion-between-manoz-biswas-and-brasofilo).

Comment: It's better to improve the question when someone asks for clarifications. (cleaned up some of my comments)